# Does $\sin(\sin(\sin\cdots(\sin1)\cdots) \rightarrow 0 $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry

Stuck on homework problem (not this), if I can prove as a lemma that the sequence $$\sin(\sin(\sin\cdots(\sin1)\cdots) \rightarrow  0  $$ then I'm done. It's monotonic and decreasing and bounded by 0 and 1 respectively, so it converges, though is it truly $0$ ?

Comment: Hint: what solutions are there to the equation x = sin(x)

Comment: yup, now I get it... wonder if that's what they expect of us.

Comment: See 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45283/compute-lim-limits-n-to-infty-sin-sin-dots-sin-n/45287#45287

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: From what you stated, you've proven that it converges to some limit, call it $L$. You know that $0 \leq L \leq 1$. Do you see an identity that $L$ satisfies with respect to sine?

Comment: sin(L)=L as they're both limits of the sequence? and then L=0. Wow.

Comment: I treated this problem as a fixed point and tried to prove it via banach but it's seems like $\sin(x)$ is not a contraction map on $[0,1]$. Or not?

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive function. Start with a definition:
$$\sin(x)=x$$
This is already a dead giveaway, the only place where this holds true is at $x=0$. This is the answer, it's this simple. The $\sin(1)$ in the middle is a little misleading.

As you can see [here](https://ideone.com/vpiptY), it's slowly getting down to $0$ as you approach infinity. Also note that the test one ($\sin 1337$) isn't much different from the original because this recursive function will hold true for whatever is inside at the end.