# Find $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\underbrace{{\sin\sin\cdots\sin(x)}}_{n\text{ times}}$. Why am I wrong?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Find $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\underbrace{{\sin\sin\cdots\sin(x)}}_{n\text{ times}}$.

It is known that after the first sine, we get something in $[-1,1]$. If it is $0$ then it is constant and remains that way and so is the limit. Otherwise, $\sin x>0$ and therefore the sequence is monotonically non-increasing with an infimum $0$. Therefore converges to $0$. The is when $\sin x<0$, the sequence is monotonically non-decreasing and converges to the supremum, $0$.

I know there is the possibility of using the continuity of sine and and Heine definition of limits, but I want to understand why someone said it is incorrect.

Comment: You might want to look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/45287/148510

Comment: What is the reference for? 
Will it tell me why I am wrong?

Comment: Not quite the same, since $n$ is the argument, rather than $x$. Might be the same answer works, though. @Winther

Comment: Not the same at all. In addition, this is not what I asked. What I asked is whether or not I am wrong, and reporting my question so that I look at other solutions won't answer my needs.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Did's answer there establishes that $n$ can be relaced by any sequence $z_n$ (in particular $z_n = x$) to get the result. Anyway, since its a bit differnt I will retract the close-vote.

Answer (score 4):

How do you know, just because it is decreasing, that the infimum is $0$? It could be $1,3/4,5/8,\dots.$

The reason the limit is $0$ is that $x_{n+1}=\sin x_n$, and decreasing but positive means that the limit of both sides is $x=\sin x$, and if $x\in(0,1)$, $0<\sin x<x$, so the only limit can be $x=0$.

You can see that $\frac{\sin x}{x}<1$ for $x\in(0,1]$ since it is $\cos h$ for some $h\in(0,x)$ by the mean value theorem.

Comment: Because if $a>0$ is the infimum, then $\sin a< a$ which is a contradiction... Isn't that so?

Comment: Do you say by that that the infimum of $\sin x$ is not to be found?

Comment: @MeitarAbarbanel You aren't looking for $\inf_x \sin x$, You are looking for $\inf_n x_n$. That's two different problems. The point is that you need to prove that $\inf_n x_n=0$. Also, you only said monotonically non-increasing, not actually strictly monotonically decreasing.

Comment: That is because it might be constant. Otherwise it is strict...
So I practically have to prove that $\inf=0$ (which was given to us as an exercise before and we are freely allowed to use)... That does not mean, though, I am not correct, I hope...

Comment: You aren't incorrect, you've merely made an assertion without an argument. You don't know that $\inf x_n = 0$ without an argument, but you assert it is true. @MeitarAbarbanel

Comment: +1 Very nice. Just curous, do you think there are other ways to find this limit?