# Prove sequence ${x_{n + 1}} = \sin {x_n},{x_1} = 1 $ has a limit

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Prove that the sequence defined by $${x_{n + 1}} = \sin {x_n},\ {x_1} = 1$$ 
>   has a limit.

Ok, I want to prove by Weierstrass:

1. This sequence is monotonically decreasing
2. Sequence is bounded

How can I do it?

Comment: "Sequece is limited" do you mean sequence is "bounded"?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45283

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** The inequality $\sin(x) \le x$ holds for all $x \ge 0$. The second assertion is trivial.

Comment: I think you need $0\le \sin x$ for $0 \le x \le 1$ to keep your hint applicable. Saying $-1 \le \sin x \le 1$ for all $x$ is not enough.

Comment: I thought about it. I didn't think that $x \ge 0$ is trivial. Ok, thanks!

Comment: @Henry It's ok if hints are just hints and not complete :)