# what are the properties of this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can we assert that this sequence is convergent or divergent?

$$u_o = a, \text{ and }  \forall n \in \mathbb{N} : u_{n+1} = \sin(u_n)$$

What is the limit of $u_{n}$ if a=$\frac{\pi}{4}$

[image]

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) rather than images when posting mathematics on this site. I fixed your last one with the sine limits, and samjoe fixed this one, but that picture is borderline unintelligible. We would appreciate it if you did it on your own. Also, I would like to repeat what I said on your last question: Write a sentence or three about what you've tried, and what made it not work, because without it we can't really help you.

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1411833/prove-sequence-x-n-1-sin-x-n-x-1-1-has-a-limit

Comment: Related Part II https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45283/compute-lim-limits-n-to-infty-sin-sin-dots-sin-n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for any $a>0$: $$0\le u_1=\sin(a)\le 1$$
for any $x \in [0;1]$: $\sin(x)<x$ thats why sequence is decreasing and all elements of this sequence is positive. Thats why the sequence have limit.

Comment: Why $u_1\geq 0$?

Comment: at first I suggest that $a>0$ for negative parameter $a$ should be use same points but the sequence will be increasing

Comment: I meant why if $a>0$ $u_1\geq 0$, the $\sin x$ function oscilates between $-1$ and $1$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: @clark you are right

Answer (score 0):

The limit shown by aid78 corresponds to a fixed point hence satisfies
$$
\sin(x)=x
$$
which gives us one possible limit : $0$.

So $\displaystyle \left(u_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

It is convergent, and the limit is zero. It follows quite nicely from interpreting the sine geometrically. Given $a\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \lbrace 0\rbrace$, then $\mathrm{sin}(a)\in [-1,1]$ is the height given by the arc of $a$ on the unit circle. At most $\mathrm{sin}(a)=\pm 1$ and subsequent sines are shorter in length since the arc $\mathrm{sin}(\pi /2)> \mathrm{sin}(1) > \cdots$ (think about it), i.e. $$|u_1| > |u_2| > |u_3| > \dots $$
So this tends to zero. Note that for $a=0$, this would yield $|u_i|=|u_j|=0$ for all $i,j\in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

Fast answer. This sequence tends to zero, relatively slowly, in a similar fashion to the sequence
$$
|b_0|<1, \quad b_{n+1}=b_n-\frac{b_n^3}{6}.
$$

Explanation. Clearly, $u_n\to 0$, since it is strictly decreasing, if $\sin u_1>0$ or
strictly increasing, if $\sin u_1<0$, due to the fact that
$0<\sin x<x$, if $\frac{\pi}{2}>x>0$, or $x<\sin x<0$, if $-\frac{\pi}{2}<x<0$,

Using Stoltz Theorem, we get that 
$$
\lim\frac{u_{n}}{n^k}=\lim\frac{u_{n+1}-u_n}{kn^{k-1}}=-\lim\frac{u_n-\sin{u_n}}{kn^{k-1}}=-\lim\frac{u_n^3}{6kn^{k-1}}
$$
Hence
$$
k-1=3k\quad\Longrightarrow\quad k=-\frac{1}{2}
$$
and therefore $u_n=\mathcal O(n^{-1/2})$.

Next, we obtain that
$$
a=\lim\frac{u_{n}}{n^{-1/2}}=\lim\frac{u_n^3}{3n^{-3/2}}=\frac{a^3}{3}
$$
and thus
$$
\frac{u_n}{\sqrt{3}n^{-1/2}}\to 1.
$$