# Repeated applications of cos function converges around $0.7390851$

Tags: trigonometry, dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems, stability-theory, fixed-points

I set my calculator to radian mode. I enter any random number $x$. Then I repeatedly apply cosine to that number, getting the sequence $$\cos x, \cos(\cos x), \cos(\cos(\cos x)) \ldots$$ and so on. No matter what $x$ I start with, it always converges around $x^* = 0.7390851$. Obviously, $x^*$ is the solution of $\cos x=x$. But why does repeated application of $\cos$ converge around this number?

Comment: I know there was a question asked about $sin$ a few weeks ago exactly but I can't find it

Comment: Maybe https://math.stackexchange.com/q/45283/344419

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of possibilities:

1. The sequence will converge.
2. The sequence will diverge.
3. The sequence will cycle.

You can check that if $x$ is a fixed point of $f$ and $|f'(x)|<1$ then the fixed point is stable (i.e., the sequence will converge). Validate this for your particular problem. More details can be found at [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_theory#Overview_in_dynamical_systems).

Comment: Can't it chaotically oscillate? (of course not in case of cos(x))

Comment: @lesnik If you mean e.g. like $x/\sin x $ with $x\to \infty$? how is this different from divergence?

Comment: Something like "several values around 2, than several values around 5, than again several values around 2, without some obvious pattern". Something like strange attractor? I do not know the answer, just curious.

Comment: @lesnik i've never seen something like this -- in theory possible but in this type of a setting unlikely... not even sure if we can produce such behavior iterating common functions...